# Finding the bootstrap affix plugin js only file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sticky

Where can i get the affix plugin JS, without having to load the whole bootstrap JS?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually customize what you want your bootstrap package to contain using http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ or you can just find the code for #affix within bootstrap and extract it to a separate JS file your self. Just beware some JS libraries are dependent on others.